# meaning of state in Delete items from state array - useReducer

Tags: react-redux, react-state-management

Hi all i am  new to react hooks.Please explain what is the meaning of state.items in DELETE_ITEM case.Is this a single object if yes then how.

```
let initialState = {
  items: [
   {
       name: 'A',
       age: 23
   },
    {
       name: 'B',
       age: 20
      },
      {
      name: 'C',
      age: 29
      }
  ]
}
const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   switch(action.type){
 case DELETE_ITEM:
return {
...state,
items: state.items.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload)
}
   }
}
```

Comment: This code has nothing to do with `react hooks`, this block of code is actually a `reducer`. You have to check how to implement `redux` in reactjs, since I dont know what middle ware you are using, you need to check the appropriate middle ware documentation. Two type commonly used are `redux thunk` and `redux saga`. You can also refer youtube videos which gives you a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state.items` is the `items` object from your state. It starts off as described in `initialState`. That's the initial value. Then, in the reducer, subsequent actions such as `DELETE_ITEM` might alter that value.

The current state of that `items` value is what you have in `state.items`. Hence, the name. It's not a single object, it's the entire items array.

Comment: Can you explain why we have written state two times 1) ...state 2) again item:state.items.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload) simply what is the difference between ...state and simple state

Comment: @user11657014 you should read a little about redux and reducers. Each reducer method changes your current `state`. In your case you only have `items` in your state so you can skip the 1) `...state`, but it's a practice to write it like that, because that way you first return the entire state with `...state`, and then set the parameters you want with some values - in your case you are setting the `items` param with a filtered version of what you had before in your state, hence the 2) `state.items.filter...`